# Unable to clone git repository

Tags: git

When I clone the git repository, I got below error,

```
Cloning into 'samples'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://182.101.71.48:12453/devel/git/samples/samples.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

Please, help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apply below command,

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

then, clone git repository.

Comment: Thank you Michel Jord...